Running a React and Aspnet project on local network
i have been building a server manager for DayZ for a while now and recently I migrated my files into a new project with Asp.NET backend and React and TypeScript frontend.
The Server itself works well, but I can't get it to show in the local network.
I tried changing the localhost to 0.0.0.0 everywhere and also added the "--host" to the start command which only helped for debugging.
When starting the project on Debug it starts the frontend like this:
 VITE v5.3.3  ready in 192 ms

  ➜  Local:   https://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: https://10.9.0.4:5173/
  ➜  Network: https://192.168.178.20:5173/
  ➜  Network: https://172.26.64.1:5173/
  ➜  press h + enter to show help

But when starting the published project I get this output:
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\...\...\Test

Edit:
I am using Visual Studio where I used the template for Asp.NET and React tsx to create the project
Edit 2:
The necessary ports in the firewall are open and the machine it is running in is pingable
Edit 3:
I tried changing all mentions of localhost to 0.0.0.0, but it still ran on localhost after build

please mention the IDE you use

0.0.0.0 represents the address of all local network interfaces. It should not be used as a local network address.
If you want to use the local network, you could consider localhost, 127.0.0.1, and directly find the local IP address by entering ipconfig in cmd.

I found that I could put the URL "http://0.0.0.0:5040" or whatever port I need and then have it open on the local network

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
